# Jaibroken iPhone sms.db file not updating right away (sms.db-wal)

Tags: jailbreak, sms

I am developing my own "back up sms system", so my sms.db is backed up few times in a day (whenever I use SBStoggle button to make a backup).

I've encountered a problem with sms.db-wal not passing data to sms.db right away, it stores newest SMS/iMessages for how long (? - assumed once per day or once in 30hrs) and after while it passes data to the sms.db file.

Is there any way to force this process?

I've found threads about this on MacForums but no answer there, I've looked in iphonewikipedia there is nothing to use either.

(I am looking for a command)

thanks for any comments or suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever connection to sms.db closes all data from sms.db-wal are synced to sms.db.

Easiest workaround is to copy all 3files
sms.db, sms.db-wal and sms.db-sch into "desired folder" an run any kind of action with sqlite3 command (output it into /dev/null) after this session closes data are synced into sms.db

Comment: There isn't much documentation on the Internet about the sms.db, so it's good to see some more people taking interest in it. Thanks for your contribution to the community.

Comment: Hello sir, there is tons of information about sms.db on the web ;) [sms.wiki](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Messages), [sms iOS 6](http://linuxsleuthing.blogspot.sk/2012/10/whos-texting-ios6-smsdb.html) My question was more about sqlite3 than sms.db